# three.js: How to sample values of a texture, and add a rendered object at that location based on the value?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am a beginner in three.js, so pardon me if this question is a little high-level.

I want to render a map in bird's eye view, and based on the value (e.g. color) on the map, I want to render and add a different object (e.g. a house, tree, rock) at that location. For example, if the map area is green, I would render and add a tree there.

Essentially, I'm trying to figure out how the rendering on this [site](https://chartogne-taillet.com/en) is done. As far as I can tell, they have some [terrain data](https://chartogne-taillet.com/img/terrainData1.6ab6692c.jpg) in maps that are colored by land use. What I'm trying to figure out is how they use that information to render the cool houses and trees.